# UIImageView in UITableViewCell not getting highlighted when cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UITableView` where each cell contains an `UIImageView` of a product (loaded asynchronously but always with a solid white background) and a `UILabel`. When I click on it the selected cell gets highlighted but not the `UIImageView`. I knew there was this property

```
imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imagedNamed:@"product_highlighted"];
```

but it's clear this works only with static images while, in this case, I'm working with a dynamic one so I don't have the image till it gets loaded.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you need the image highlighted as well? This would require you to change the image or use a 2nd image as you have mentioned. I am not sure if the image can have a transparent background or else that would work.

Answer (score 2):

You should create your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and override `setHighlighted:animated`:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    [imageView setHighlighted:highlighted];
}
```

From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setHighlighted:animated:):

> Note that for highlighting to work properly, you must fetch the cell’s
>   label (or labels) using the textLabel (and detailTextLabel properties
>   and set the label’s highlightedTextColor property; for images, get the
>   cell’s image using the imageView property and set the UIImageView
>   object’s highlightedImage property.

Comment: just tried, it doesn't work. The imageView is not affected by the selection

Comment: did you set the imageview's highlightedImage property?

Comment: it's an asynchronous uiimageview so we don't have the image till it's done with the loading

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. It works if the background of the image is white. I've added to the *TableviewDidSelectRow* method

```
- (UIImage*) addLayerTo:(UIImage*)source withAlpha:(double)alpha
{
    CGSize size = [source size];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [source drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return testImg;
}
```

It basically adds a black layer with a specific alpha transparency which will merge seamlessly with the cell selected background. I took inspiration from [this article](http://viget.com/inspire/equating-color-and-transparency)